# How to close all opened chrome with Watir::Browser or reuse already opened?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir-webdriver

The problem is that the app is persistent and works as a layer between client and intranet site. When client does a request, server opens new chrome window with ChromeDriver, authenticates, requests information, parses it and shows to the client. Client can do tens or hundreds requests to fetch new data. But if client doesn't work for around 10 minutes next his request opens new chrome window.

I couldn't find any methods with Watir::Browser to reuse already opened window or at least close already opened except

```
system("taskkill /t /f /im chrome.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.windows.each do |window|
  window.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this for closing all windows.

```
def close_all_windows
  loop do
    begin
      Watir::Chrome.attach(:title, //).close
    rescue Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException
      break
    rescue
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

If I were you though I will prefer just switching the focus onto an already opened window. Like so below:

```
browser.window(:title => "bbc.co.uk").use do
  # your code
end
```